# URL rewriting not working from index.php?id=2 to /2

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL called

```
http://localhost:8080/text/index.php?id=2
```

and I have to redirect on

```
http://localhost:8080/text/2
```

So I added the below code in the .htaccess but it's not working

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

I refer to the below two links. Is there any issue with my code?

[common-htaccess-redirects-19-6-2018](https://support.cartika.com/portal/en/kb/articles/common-htaccess-redirects-19-6-2018) and [htaccess-rules](https://linchpinseo.com/htaccess-rules/)

[image]

After suggested answer, I tried below code

**HTML**

```
  <a href="index.php?id=1">Register</a>
  <a href="index.php?id=2">login</a>
```

or

```
<a href="1">Register</a>
 <a href="2">login</a>
```

**.htaccess code**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Well... `^([^/d]+)/?$ ` certainly won't match `text/2` ...

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. This considers that you are
hitting URL `http://localhost:8080/text/2` in browser.

```
##Making RewriteEngine ON here.
RewriteEngine ON
##Placing conditions to check if these are non-existing pages only.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##Writing rule to rewrite to index.php with needed variable here.
RewriteRule ^[\w-]+/(\d+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

***Issues in OP's attempt:*** You are trying to attempt to match digits in starting where your url doesn't have digits, so rather use `[\w-]+` with it. Also use `QSA,L` flags with your rewrite rule to handle query string and come out of the rule in case this is executing.

Comment: Give me sometime, let me check the answer

Comment: @user9437856, sure.

Comment: What HTML link i have to use here <a href="/2">redirect me</a> ? i tried like this also <a href="index.php?id=2">redirect me</a>

Comment: @user9437856, I believe you need to give something like `<a href="http://localhost:8080/text/2">redirect me</a>` but you can decide it better :) basically what rules are doing: they are rewriting from friendly url to non-friendly(php file) urls in backend.

Comment: I tried and I am getting objects not found. Updated screenshot in the question

Comment: @user9437856, ok, could you please do let me know details, where your htaccess file is residing? And where is your index.php file is?

Comment: htdocs->text(foldername)->index.php and .htaccess. Inshort in the root folder.

Comment: @user9437856, ok, so when you simply hit `http://localhost:8080/text/2` in browser what you get?

Comment: I am getting Object not found!.. Screenshot attached the question along with the URL

Comment: @user9437856, you are giving port `8080`, try giving port `80` in url? That's default port of apache(in case you haven't changed it), let me know how it goes.

Comment: Actually, I am using xampp and testing on localhost(local server). I haven't change the port number. I got it by default after installing the xampp. I am using MAC air.

Comment: @user9437856, If you are using xampp then you could try to put your index.php in your `.../xampp/htdocs` folder once?

Comment: I have this path htdocs->text(foldername)->index.php and .htaccess. and I believe there is no issue with folder and port .. I created one more folder called test2 and there I also got the same issue.

Comment: @user9437856, you need to check your httpd.conf file I believe that what is your DOCUMENT_ROOT value is set there, kindly check it once and let me know then.

Comment: I tested on live server, There also I am getting the same issue.

Comment: @user9437856, When I tested these rules in my localhost I get 200 OK result, by curl command, these are working fine for me.

Comment: I don't know, It's redirecting on the 404 pages. Can you check your code again? till the time I am checking with my code..

Comment: @user9437856, I have tested it worked successfully for me, you need to check your document root where it's set

Comment: I shared the same code with my colleagues. He also getting the same issue.

Comment: @user9437856, not sure it's working fine for me, how about checking httd.conf file that what is there for document root entry?

Comment: Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Comment: @user9437856. Try putting `--------` this dummy line in your htaccess file and save it then hit any URL if you getting 500 internal error then it means your htaccess is enabled else it's not, let me know how it goes 

Comment: Yes, I added dummy line and I got 500 error server error https://prnt.sc/136jv65

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232659/discussion-between-user9437856-and-ravindersingh13).

Comment: @user9437856, i would request you to chat here it's late night I can't join chat room please.

Comment: Sure. Can you check again my code? is there any issue with it?

Comment: @user9437856, actually your direct localhost url is giving 404 that is the issue we need to check, href value is nothing but direct url value only.

Comment: @user9437856, could you please do let me know how it went? Thank you.